# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure after copying ASP.NET Core 1.1 to another machine

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I upgraded my ASP.NET Core app from 1.0 to 1.1 following procedures from Official ASP.NET site. The app runs fine on its original location on Windows 10 (upgraded from win 7). But when I copied the app on another machine (Win 7) that also has latest VS2015-Update3 installed and installed [NET Core 1.0.1 tools Preview 2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015) , the app compiles fine but gives the following error: `HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure`

**Moreover, the event log shows the following**:

`Failed to start process with commandline '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" -p "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -a "C:\DotNET2015\ABCTest\src\ABCTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\ABCTest.dll" -wd "C:\DotNET2015\ABCTest\src\ABCTest" -wbe Global\Build500340c7-6e16-4a08-b314-ff5fd51b1dcb -lse Global\Launchb628508b-6e25-455f-9afa-6092434506ed', ErrorCode = '0x80004005'.`

**NOTE** App is running on default IISEXPRESS

**project.json**:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-ABCTest-6af8ade3-87ff-4468-a9ce-8bb69c696ab8",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.1.0-preview4-final"  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you tried `dontnet restore`?

Comment: @J.Doe Could you please tell what would this command do? Would this revert back some packaes?

Comment: Restore packages from NuGet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install .NET Core 1.1 runtime on the machine you copied your application to. The one you installed was 1.0.1.

Comment: @Powel The deployment is not  of a runtime app. It's just a copy of the entire VS2015 project to another machine that also has VS2015 and the same project will be used there for development. Do I need runtime there or an SDK?

Comment: Still you need runtime. If the application you created is not standalone (and it isn't) it won't carry the runtime and can't be started.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I updated NuGet packages in Visual Studio.
In my case, the solution was to downgrade packages:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel from 1.1.0 to 1.0.1
Microsoft.NETCore.App from 1.1.0 to 1.0.1

..and then things were back to normal again.